# How to create an Object using each in java from an array

Tags: java, for-loop, each

Hi i am trying  to do this
and i cant understand why
I am trying to create Pointe instance of an array  from for each
but it is coming out as null

```
Point arr[]=new Point[5]
for(Point o:arr){
o=new Point();
}
```

Comment: You need to _assign_ values in the array. I would suggest `Point[] array = Stream.generate(Point::new).limit(5).toArray(Point[]::new);`. Also, please use `Point[] arr` rather than `Point arr[]` - the latter syntax is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You inicialize the termporary variable `o` in the loop, not the items in the outer array:

```
Point arr[]=new Point[5];
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    arr[i] = new Point();
}
```